# Are all elements in xs:sequence required?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given following xsd

```
<xs:sequence minoccurs=0>
            <xs:element name="AAA"/>
            <xs:element name="BBB">
</xs:sequence>
```

Can I produce xml with only one of the elements AAA or BBB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say how many occurrences are allowed by adding the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attributes to `xs:element`. The defaults are `minOccurs="1"`, `maxOccurs="1"`. To make an element optional, set `minOccurs="0"`.

(This is very basic. You need a better way of getting such basic information than asking on StackOverflow. There are a couple of good books on XSD, from Priscilla Walmsley and from Eric van der Vlist. I would recommend anyone trying to code in XSD to have one of these, or preferably both, open on their desk.)

Comment: Thank you, my question is: Can I use only one element of the sequence? From another post: "Generally speaking occurrence constraints ( minOccurs or maxOccurs ) on element groups (sequences or choices) mean that the whole group can be repeated" - Does it mean, that the whole group must be present? Or can I use just a part? I couldn't find the answer to this question in the net, so I posted it here.

Comment: If an element has minOccurs="1" (which is the default) then it must be present.